# Call pcntl_fork twice cause PHP CGI dead loop

Tags: fork, php

```
function spawn($exec, $args = array()) {
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid < 0)
    return false;
else if ($pid == 0) {
    $ppid = getmypid();
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid < 0)
        file_put_contents('/tmp/error.log', "fork failed: ${cmd} ". implode(' ', $args). "\n");
    else if ($pid == 0) {
        pcntl_waitpid($ppid, $status);
        pcntl_exec($exec, $args);
    }
    else
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

This works well in CLI mode.
But for php-fpm it causes the caller dead loop and then a timeout.
Why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because calling `exit()` under FPM doesn't cause the parent process to exit -- it just makes it clean up the request, then return to the pool of available worker processes. Since it never actually exits, the `pcntl_waitpid` ends up waiting forever.

As Roman Newaza notes, you should really avoid the `pcntl` functions under FPM (and, in general, outside CLI).

Comment: OK. It seems to be almost the exactly reason except that I think pcntl_waitpid should block instead of dead loop.

Answer (score 0):

Process Control should not be enabled within a web server environment and unexpected results may happen if any Process Control functions are used within a web server environment: [PCNTL/Introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcntl.php)